# How do I compile C++11 code to webassembly?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++, llvm-clang, webassembly

I've been trying to port the following code to webassembly:

```cpp
#include "gmtl/gmtl/Vec.h"
#include "gmtl/gmtl/VecOps.h"
#include "gmtl/gmtl.h"
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono> 
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace gmtl;

class Settings{
  public:
    Settings(float _repulsion, float _epsilon, float _inner_distance, float _attraction, float _friction, float _gravity, float _min_start_pos, float _max_start_pos){
      repulsion = _repulsion;
      epsilon = _epsilon;
      inner_distance = _inner_distance;
      attraction = _attraction;
      friction = _friction;
      gravity = _gravity;

      min_start_pos = _min_start_pos;
      max_start_pos = _max_start_pos;
    }

    float repulsion;
    float epsilon;
    float inner_distance;
    float attraction;
    float friction;
    float gravity;
    float min_start_pos;
    float max_start_pos;
};

class Randomator {
  private:
    float min;
    float max;

  public:
    Randomator(){
      srand(time(NULL));
    }

    float get(){
      return rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    }
};

class Vertex {
  public:

    Vertex(int vertex_id){
      Randomator ra;
      position = gmtl::Vec3f(ra.get(), ra.get(), ra.get());

      id = vertex_id;
    }

    int id;
    gmtl::Vec3f position;
    gmtl::Vec3f velocity;
    gmtl::Vec3f acceleration;

    gmtl::Vec3f repulsion_forces;
    gmtl::Vec3f attraction_forces;

    static gmtl::Vec3f pairwise_repulsion(const gmtl::Vec3f& one, const gmtl::Vec3f& other, const Settings& settings){
      gmtl::Vec3f diff = one - other;
      // gmtl::Vec3f diff = *(this->position) - *(other->position);
      float abs_diff = length(diff);
      return  (settings.repulsion / 
               ((settings.epsilon + abs_diff)*(settings.epsilon + abs_diff)) * 
               (diff / abs_diff));
    }

    bool operator==(const Vertex& other){
      return other.id == id;
    }

    string toString(){
      stringstream ss;
      ss << "Vertex " << id;
      return ss.str();
    }
};


class Edge {
  public:
    Edge(int edge_id, Vertex* _source, Vertex* _target){
      source = _source;
      target = _target;
      id = edge_id;
    };

    int id;
    Vertex* source;
    Vertex* target;
    bool directed = false;

    string toString(){
      stringstream ss;
      ss << "Edge " << id;
      return ss.str();
    }

    bool operator==(const Edge& other){
      return id == other.id;
    }
};

class BarnesHutNode3 {
  public:
    vector<Vertex> inners; // should probably be a pointer
    map<string, BarnesHutNode3*> outers;
    gmtl::Vec3f center_sum;
    int count;
    Settings settings;

    BarnesHutNode3(const Settings& _settings) : settings(_settings){
      count = 0;
    }

    gmtl::Vec3f center(){
      return this->center_sum / (float)this->count;
    }

    void place_inner(Vertex& vertex){
      this->inners.push_back(vertex);
      this->center_sum += vertex.position;
    }

    void place_outer(Vertex& vertex){
      string octant = this->get_octant(vertex.position);
      this->outers[octant] = new BarnesHutNode3(settings);
      this->outers[octant]->insert(vertex);
    }

    void insert(Vertex& vertex){
      if(this->inners.size() == 0){
        this->place_inner(vertex);
      }else{
        gmtl::Vec3f center = this->center();
        gmtl::Vec3f pos = vertex.position;
        float distance = sqrt((center[0] - pos[0])*(center[0] - pos[0]) + 
                             (center[1] - pos[1])*(center[1] - pos[1]) +
                             (center[2] - pos[2])*(center[2] - pos[2]));

        if(distance <= settings.inner_distance){
          this->place_inner(vertex);
        }else{
          this->place_outer(vertex);
        }
      }

      this->count++;
    }

    string get_octant(gmtl::Vec3f& position){
      gmtl::Vec3f center = this->center();
      string x = center[0] < position[0] ? "l" : "r";
      string y = center[1] < position[1] ? "u" : "d";
      string z = center[2] < position[2] ? "i" : "o";
      return x+y+z;
    }

    void estimate(Vertex& vertex, gmtl::Vec3f& force, gmtl::Vec3f (*force_fn)(const gmtl::Vec3f& p1, const gmtl::Vec3f& p2, const Settings& settings), const Settings& settings){
      if(find(this->inners.begin(), this->inners.end(), vertex) != this->inners.end()){ // todo: make better, maintain a set or something
        for(auto i=0; i<this->inners.size(); i++){
          if(this->inners[i].id != vertex.id){
            gmtl::Vec3f f = force_fn(vertex.position, this->inners[i].position, settings);
            force += f;
          }
        }
      }else{
        gmtl::Vec3f f = force_fn(vertex.position, this->center(), settings) * (float)this->inners.size();
        force += f;
      }

      for(auto &it : this->outers){
        this->outers[it.first]->estimate(vertex, force, force_fn, settings);
      }
    }

    string toString(){
      return "BarnesHutNode3";
    }

    unsigned int size(){
      return this->count;
    }
};

class Graph {
  public:
    Graph(const Settings& _settings) : settings(_settings){
      vertex_id = 0;
      edge_id = 0;
    };

    void add_vertex(const Vertex& vertex){
      V.push_back(vertex);
    }

    void add_edge(const Edge& edge){
      E.push_back(edge);
    }

    void remove_vertex(Vertex vertex){
      V.erase(find(V.begin(), V.end(), vertex));
    }

    void remove_edge(Edge edge){
      E.erase(find(E.begin(), E.end(), edge));
    }

    int vertex_id = 0;
    int edge_id = 0;
    vector<Vertex> V;
    vector<Edge> E;
    Settings settings;

    void layout(){
      // calculate repulsions

      BarnesHutNode3 tree(settings);
      for(Vertex& vertex : this->V){
        tree.insert(vertex);
      }
      for(Vertex& vertex : this->V){
        vertex.repulsion_forces = gmtl::Vec3f();
        tree.estimate(
          vertex,
          vertex.repulsion_forces,
          &Vertex::pairwise_repulsion, 
          settings);
      }

      // calculate attractions 
      for(Edge edge : this->E){
        gmtl::Vec3f attraction = (edge.source->position - edge.target->position) * (-1 * settings.attraction);
        if(edge.directed){
          gmtl::Vec3f sp = edge.source->position;
          gmtl::Vec3f tp = edge.target->position;

          float distance = sqrt((sp[0] - tp[0])*(sp[0] - tp[0]) + 
                                      (sp[1] - tp[1])*(sp[1] - tp[1]) +
                                      (sp[2] - tp[2])*(sp[2] - tp[2]));
          gmtl::Vec3f gravity = gmtl::Vec3f(0.0f, settings.gravity/distance, 0.0f);
          edge.source->attraction_forces -= attraction;
          edge.target->attraction_forces += attraction;
        }
      }

      // update vertices
      for(Vertex& vertex : this->V){
        gmtl::Vec3f friction = vertex.velocity * settings.friction;
        vertex.acceleration += vertex.repulsion_forces - vertex.attraction_forces - friction;
        vertex.velocity += vertex.acceleration;
        vertex.position += vertex.velocity;
      }
    }
};


gmtl::Vec3f avg_position(const Graph&);
vector<gmtl::Vec3f> average_positions(int, int, int, const Settings&);

class Experiment {
  public:
    Experiment(float& _variable, const std::vector<float>& _values, const Settings& settings){
      variable = &_variable;
      values = _values;

      for(auto value : values){
        *(this->variable) = value;
        this->histories.push_back(average_positions(50, 10, 30, settings));
      }
    }

    float* variable;
    std::vector<float> values;
    std::vector<std::vector<gmtl::Vec3f> > histories;

    static float length(gmtl::Vec3f v){
      return sqrt(v[0]*v[0] + v[1]*v[1] + v[2]*v[2]);
    }

    static gmtl::Vec3f avg_position(const Graph& graph){
      gmtl::Vec3f position;
      for(auto vertex : graph.V){
        position += vertex.position;
      }
      return position / (float)graph.V.size();
    }

    static std::vector<gmtl::Vec3f> average_positions(int iterations, int vertices, int edges, const Settings& settings){
      vector<gmtl::Vec3f> history;
      Graph h(settings);
      for(int i=0; i<vertices; i++){
        h.add_vertex(Vertex(i));
      }
      for(int i=0; i<edges; i++){
        h.add_edge(Edge(i, &h.V[rand() % h.V.size()], &h.V[rand() % h.V.size()]));
      }

      for(int i=0; i<iterations; i++){
        h.layout();
        cout << ".";
        history.push_back(avg_position(h));
      }

      return history;
    }
};

class Main {
  public:
    static int run(int NUM_VERTICES, int NUM_EDGES){
      cout << "Welcome to foud.cpp, the meat and bones of social cartography..." << endl;
      float _repulsion = 5.0;
      float _epsilon = 0.1;
      float _inner_distance = 0.36;
      float _attraction = 0.0005;
      float _friction = 0.60;
      float _gravity = 10;

      float _min_start_pos = -1.0f;
      float _max_start_pos = 1.0f;

      srand(time(NULL));

      cout << "Creating Randomator ... ";
      Randomator ra;
      cout << "done." << endl;

      cout << "Creating Settings ... ";
      Settings settings(
        _repulsion, 
        _epsilon, 
        _inner_distance,
        _attraction,
        _friction,
        _gravity,
        _min_start_pos,
        _max_start_pos
      );
      cout << "done." << endl;

      cout << "Creating graph ... ";
      Graph graph(settings);
      cout << "done." << endl;

      cout << "Adding vertices ... ";
      for(int i=0; i<NUM_VERTICES; i++){
        graph.add_vertex(Vertex(i));
      }
      cout << "done." << endl;

      cout << "Adding edges ... ";
      for(int i=0; i<NUM_EDGES; i++){
        Vertex source = graph.V[rand() % graph.V.size()];
        Vertex temp = graph.V[rand() % graph.V.size()];
        while(graph.V.size() && temp.id != source.id){
          temp = graph.V[rand() % graph.V.size()];
        }
        Vertex target = temp;
        Edge edge(graph.edge_id++, &source, &target);
        graph.add_edge(edge);
      }
      cout << "done." << endl;

      cout << "One layout step ... ";
      auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      graph.layout();
      auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      cout << "done." << endl;

      auto dur = stop - start;

      cout << NUM_VERTICES << " vertices and " << NUM_EDGES << " edges took " << (double)dur.count() << "ms" << endl;
      return 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int v = 10000;
  int e = v*3;
  Main::run(v, e);
}
```

I know the code isn't perfect, but it compiles using `clang++ -std=c++11 fourd.cpp`, but I can't find documentation on how to make clang compile to webassembly.

I've tried looking far and wide, into the depths of google search terms, but couldn't find how to compile webassembly from c++11. I have clang installed, and nodejs, and I have pulled the emsdk.

Comment: `$ which emcc
~/Code/fourd.cpp/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.30/emcc` shows me I have emcc installed and activated, however, when I invoke it, I get an error about 
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Comment: I'm on CentOS 7

Comment: Found some instructions for getting emscripten setup: https://blog.cles.jp/item/9428

Comment: Did you follow the installation instruction from the emscripten home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to use the emscripten toolchain to compile from C++ to WebAssembly.

So assuming emcc is on your path you can compile your code

```
emcc -std=c++11 fourd.cpp -o fourd.html
```

This will create a `html`, `js` and `wasm` file.

If you are only interested in the `wasm` file you can also write

```
emcc -std=c++11 fourd.cpp -o fourd.wasm
```

But then you need to manually load the wasm file. So the last option is:

```
emcc -std=c++11 fourd.cpp -o fourd.js
```

Providing you a js file which you can include in a `html` file and the `js` file loads the `wasm` file automatically.

It's also worth checking out the emscripten tutorial to give you an overview: [emscripten tutorial](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Philipp. Could you tell me how I include the gmtl library in my compilation? I have the source code to gmtl in subfolder to this directory.

Comment: I don't know how big `gmtl` is but if it's only a few cpp files you should be able to add them into your build command and they should be linked while clang creates the LLVM bitcode. I usually use CMake and create libraries which I can then link against.

Comment: I'm still just exploring the different options. I ended up -I/including the gmtl library, after building it via emmake, I think it was.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there are some options with clang toolchain (actually modified) to compile to wasm like https://github.com/yurydelendik/wasmception  But actually I don't know how good mature they are.

The reliable way for now is to use [emscripten](https://emscripten.org). Under the hood it compiles from C++ to asm.js and then converts the result to wasm. Which doesn't always give the best possible performance, but at least both stages are quite stable.
Here is the tutorial how to use emscripten to emit wasm modules: https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/WebAssembly.html